# Get string of multiline function call from stack

Tags: python, python-2.7

**Background:**

- For proof reasons I have to extract the parameternames of a called function.
- Function calls may be coded multiline because of the companys coding guidelines

**Example:**

```
toBeMonitored(genHelloWorld(),
              10,
              20)

def toBeMonitored(a, b, c):
    varNames = inspect.stack().doParse()
    print(varNames)

def genHelloWorld():
    return "Hello World"
```

> ```
> >20)\n
> ```

**Question:** Is there any way to retrieve the full string from the stack or anywhere else:

> "toBeMonitored(genHelloWorld(),
>                     10,
>                     20)"

Comment: have you tried using decorators. That might work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This two decorators getting info from inside function and getting full text of function call (not 100% precise, function name occurrence based):

```
import inspect

def inspect_inside(func): #Inspect from function
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        print('Function:', func.__name__)
        argnames = inspect.getargspec(func).args
        for i,k in enumerate(args):
            print(argnames[i],'=',k)
        for k in kwargs:
            print(k,'=',kwargs[k])
        return func(*args, **kwargs)
    return wrapper

def inspect_outside(func): #Getting place of function call
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        frame = inspect.currentframe()
        try:
            filename = frame.f_back.f_code.co_filename
            lineno = frame.f_back.f_lineno
            with open(filename) as f:
                filelines = f.readlines()
                caller_text = ""
                for i in range(lineno-1,0,-1):
                    caller_text = filelines[i] + caller_text
                    if filelines[i].find(func.__name__) >= 0:
                        break
                print(caller_text)
        finally:
            del frame
        return func(*args, **kwargs)
    return wrapper

@inspect_inside
def toBeMonitored(a,b,c):
    ...

toBeMonitored("Hello World",
              10,
              20)

@inspect_outside
def toBeMonitored(a,b,c):
    ...

toBeMonitored("Hello World",
              10,
              20)
```

Result:

```
Function: toBeMonitored
a = Hello World
b = 10
c = 20

toBeMonitored("Hello World",
              10,
              20)
```

Comment: Thank you very much!
Unfortunately this is not what I am searching for.
It seems I picked a bad example sry for this!...
I tried to make it clearer :/

I need the names from where the toBeMonitored is called. Not from inside toBeMonitored()
Thats why I tried to use the python stack

Comment: I've add `inspect_outside` decorator, that getting place of function call.

Comment: `inspect_outside` is exactly what I was searching for @Stanislav Thank you!